# twilio master account make outbound call with subaccount validated number

Tags: twilio

I need to make outgoing calls from browser and i set capability token with the master account.

Then i make a call request to twilio from browser and return a twiml from my server.

In the twiml, i set the callerId to a **subaccount validated outgoing phone number**.

**When dial to another client, it works fine. But, if dial to a phone number it not work.**

From the debugger i saw this error:
[image]

it said callerId must be provided for TwilioClient and SIP calls when using Dial.

I dont know why, I need a help.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't create the capability token with the subaccount credentials?

Comment: no. actually we want to call to clients of other subaccounts, but that not work. so, we init all clients with the master account. For the charge reason, we want to make ountbound call with subaccount validated number.

Comment: So, in this case you are creating an outbound call to a phone number from a subaccount, so why not make the capability token with the subaccount credentials? That is what is going to create the call within the the context of the subaccount and charge it accordingly.

Comment: We just want to realize one customer with one subaccount. But, if we do that, a call from a subaccount client to another subaccount client will not work. So, we have to init all clients with the master account. But the validated numbers still in subaccounts. When make a call from client, we want to set the callerId to a subaccount number in twiml, it not work. Forget it, now we decide to use the master account only.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know you could make calls between clients in different subaccounts. In fact, if you are giving them the capability using the master account, then the client calls that are being made are being done so by the master account anyway and you are not using the subaccounts. It seems to me that this is the behaviour you need for making phone calls too. Good luck with it 